# How to call Row, Header values in other functions- Python/Airflow/Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, airflow, keyword-argument

I am using Airflow to create an etl updated script from my redshift master table. I am trying to collect the record for table1 and then update my master table accordingly. My question is how to use the kwargs argument to get the value whenever it is called.

In my below function, I collect the record of the table and put it in dictionary format(key value). In the next function, I want to be able to get the value of the column as you can see in the .format after copy_sql statement. So in the {0} parameter, it should put the value of the column named table_name in my table.

Here is my code:

```
    #Import Modules

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder, create_logger
from io import StringIO
import logging
import paramiko
import MySQLdb as sql
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import psycopg2.extras


my_master_table = 'schema1'
database_name = 'db1'
schema_name = 'schema1'
table_name = 'table1'



#Get the record of the select query 
def get_etl():
    pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgre_conn_id="postgres_default", schema='schema1')
    connection = pg_hook.get_conn()
    col_query = """
             select * from {0}
             Where database_name = '{1}'
             and schema_name = '{2}'
             and table_name = '{3}' ;
        """.format(my_master_table, database_name,schema_name, table_name)

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(col_query)
    desc = cursor.description

    column_names = [col[0] for col in desc]

    data = [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    return data

def copy_into_redshift(**kwargs):
    data = get_etl(kwargs['my_master_table'],
                            kwargs['database_name'],
                            kwargs['schema_name'],
                            kwargs['table_name'])
    copy_sql = '''COPY schema1.{0}
                  FROM 'bucket_name'
                  iam_role 'aws role'
                  REGION 'us-east-1' ESCAPE DELIMITER ',' ACCEPTANYDATE;'''.format(record['table_name'])

        pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgre_conn_id="postgres_default", schema='schema1')
        connection = pg_hook.get_conn()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(copy_sql)
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()


# Identify Default Arguments
default_args = {
    'owner': 'mae',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019,12,15),
}


#Instantiate DAG instance


dag = DAG('testing_1', description ='This is a test ', default_args = default_args, schedule_interval ='@hourly', catchup = False)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id ='new_oneee',
    python_callable = get_etl,
    dag=dag)

t2 = PythonOperator(task_id ='s3_update', python_callable = copy_into_redshift, depends_on_past= True, dag=dag )

t1 >> t2
```

Any ideas or suggestions would help.